# Нужен ли знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

М**ожет, вот он( )рай на земле?**

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, "рай на земле" - это обычное приложение, стоящее после определяемого слова, выраженного личным местоимением. В таком случае ставится запятая, а если приложение находится в конце предложения и имеет пояснительный характер, то ставится тире. Второй вариант в данном предложении больше подходит по смыслу, так как он позволяет исключить интонацию перечисления

Answer (score 1):

Какой-то знак между "он" и "рай" безусловно нужен. Тире или запятая - решать автору. Я бы поставил интонационное тире.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет однозначного ответа по той простой причине, что пир разной пунктуации - разный смысл.

---

Если *"он"* считать подлежащим, а *"рай на земле"* - сказуемым, то знаков ставить не надо, так как подлежащее выражено местоимением. Смысл в таком предложении таков: *"Он - это рай на земле"*.

---

Если же *"рай на земле"* принять за уточняющую конструкцию, то надо ставить запятую, а не тире, так как конструкция не осложнена.

---

Всё зависит от того, что хотел сказать автор.

Comment: Вопрос к администрации и опытным пользователям: как ставить абзацы в ответе?

Comment: Перед Enter поставить не менее двух пробелов.   
Получится вот так.

Comment: Сейчас попробую.  
Попробовал.

Comment: Получилось.  
Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

"Рай на земле" - это приложение при личном местоимении ОН. Нужна запятая. Мне нравится ответ Виктор1799. Только тире здесь нежелательно, ведь приложения при личном местоимении выделяются именно запятыми.

**В связи с предложенной темой**, мне кажется, стоит  обратить внимание и **на частицу "вот он":**

В построениях с оценочным и усилительным значением частицы *вот*, ***вот он*** *(оно, она, они*), *вот и, вот тебе и, вот так, ну, ну и, уж и ...* (Вот еще выдумал!; ***Вот оно легкомыслие-то!***)  открывают собою предложение или находятся непосредственно перед предикативно значимым членом (http://rusgram.narod.ru/2208-2230.html)

Но это не наш случай, мне кажется. В предложении "Может, вот он, рай на земле?" используется указательная частица ВОТ при подлежащем ОН, а не оценочно-усилительная частица "вот он (оно, она, они)" .